# How can I reroute this querystring URL?

Tags: routing

In my routes file I have this:

```
'micros-test/guest-booking/(?P<bookingId>[a-z0-9-]*)' => 'micros-test/guest-booking',
```

Which works fine for URLS like this:

> /en/micros-test/guest-booking/some-valid-alphanumeric-id

However I need to add another that I can't get working, this time with a querystring value, such as this:

> /en/micros-test/guest-reset-password?token=some-valid-alphanumeric-id

How can I get that to route to my endpoint and pass on the token parameter?

I've tried this but to no avail:

```
'micros-test/guest-reset-password/?token=(?P<token>[a-z0-9-]*)' => 'micros-test/guest-reset-password',
```

What have I got wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - looks like it's the specific use of `token` as a parameter that's causing the problem.

---

The route doesn't need to account for the get parameters, so it only needs to be `micros-test/guest-reset-password`.

You then fetch the parameter using `craft.request.getParam('token')`.

Comment: The problem I have is that when the token is there, the route doesn't resolve and so results in a 404.

Comment: Sorry you're correct, using `token` does indeed cause a 404 on an otherwise working route. Must be used by the system for something, can't say I've seen it documented though.

Comment: You can adjust it with the [tokenParam](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#tokenParam) config setting.